# How To Show Different Text On Different Shipping Methods Using Checkout -UI Extension?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

I am creating a private checkout - UI extension which could show different text on different shipping method.

but it is showing the same text for all the shipping methods.

I am using 'purchase.checkout.shipping-option-item.render-after' target and returning *<BlockStack>* inside extension function

```
return (
    <BlockStack>
      <TextBlock>
       sample text for standard
      </TextBlock>
    </BlockStack>
);
```

and it is showing the expected text but it is showing the same text for all the shipping methods. How to make this text for only a particular shipping method ?